# Listed list return index value

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Suppose I have the following nested list:

```
l = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
```

I want to get the maximum value of the second column, in this case 12. I do it like this:

```
max([i[1] for i in l])
```

Now, I need to grab the corresponding value: 11. How can I grab this value?

Comment: I am getting `12` for same code

Comment: Your title mentions the index but your question doesn't. What exactly are you trying to get?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the key you max over:

```
max(l, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```